# Similar query, run times much different

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a script that build some # tables and the result is a `SELECT *` query.

**This query where I plug in the actual variables used runs in a few seconds**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    #rec_subids 
    INNER JOIN #max_payment_dt
        ON 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN  vw_staging_lpmt
        ON lpmt_subid = 1008
        AND lpmt_asofdt >= '2017-09-20'
```

**This query where the variables actually come from the # tables runs in 10+ minutes**

```
select * from #max_payment_dt
2017-09-20 00:00:00.000
select * from #rec_subids
1008
```

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    #rec_subids 
    INNER JOIN #max_payment_dt
        ON 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN  vw_staging_lpmt
        ON lpmt_subid = r_subid
        AND lpmt_asofdt >= max_asofdt
```

Any thoughts of how I can speed up the second query without changing the `vw_staging_lpmt`?

These are 2 columns - 1 record, an ID and as Date. I understand the hardcoding would work better but can't hardcode here.

Here is the [plan of the poorly performing query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyC_bleJz).

Here is the [plan of the much better performing query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1FK4lgJM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query has constants in it, and optimizer knows them when it makes a plan.

So it can use statistics on `lpmt_subid` and `lpmt_asofdt`, it estimated the predicate `lpmt_asofdt >= '2017-09-20'` as 74698 rows.

Your `lease_payments` has at least 7 mln of rows (if it was smaller server would not decide to make 74698 lookups but opted for full scan), but the statistics for `'2017-09-20'` is known, server decides that if it make index seek + lookups it will cost less then full clustered index scan.

When insted of constants you use temporary tables column values, server has no idea about what these values are, so it cannot use column statistics and does make full clustered index scan of `lease_payments`.

You use SQL Server 2012, it estimates cardinality of filtering by non-unique unknown value as `power(TableCardinality, 3./4)`, it seems that your `lease_payments`table has about 3.406.611.597 rows (as estimation is 14.100.800 rows when matching with `#rec_subids`).

You can fix this by assigning `r_subid`, `max_asofdtto` local variables first (if you are sure that your temp tables are of 1 row each) and then adding `recompile` option to sniff these variables:

```
declare @max_asofdt date =
(select top 1 max_asofdt 
from #max_payment_dt);

declare @r_subid int =
(select top 1 r_subid 
from #rec_subids);


SELECT *
FROM 
    #rec_subids 
    INNER JOIN #max_payment_dt
        ON 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN  vw_staging_lpmt
        ON lpmt_subid = @r_subid
        AND lpmt_asofdt >= @max_asofdt
option(recompile);
```

Comment: Thank you sepupic Rewriting with variables works much better. Now need to rewrite the code because there will be more than one r_subid that needs to be passed in.